# NumPy fast iteration trough image

Tags: python, performance, numpy, opencv, computer-vision

I'm trying to get the extreme points in a binary image that has a rectangular shape (more or less).
[Binary image in which I want to find some rectangular bound around my rectangular (black) object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73iLD.png)

I would like to get 4 points like this ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIQjh.png)) in order to use cv2.minAreaRect(points) on them and obtain a bounding box. The issue is that my current algorithm is extremely slow in finding those bounds because I have to iterate through this binary image 4 times (2D NumPy array).

```
def findCornerOne(frame):
    #threshold that handles the case when you have some noise around your object (as in the photo 
    #above)
    global thresholdVal
    x = frame.shape[0]
    y = frame.shape[1]
    point = None
    firstFound = True
    count = 0
    for i in range(0, y):
        for j in range(0, x):
            if frame[j][i] != 0:
                if firstFound:
                    point = [i, j]
                    firstFound = False
                 count += 1
            else:
                if count <= thresholdVal:
                    firstFound = True
                    count = 0
                else:
                    return point

    return None
```

Is there any way speeding this up just with NumPy and standard python (without any libraries)? I was thinking about using numpy.where but I don't know how to specify on what axis I'm going to search first and find the bounding points.

In the end, I would like to obtain some points like the red ones in the image:[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIQjh.png)

Comment: You don’t want to use any libraries, then why tag OpenCV? What is the reason you don’t want to use libraries? I think it’s short-sighted to implement this in Python. Libraries like OpenCV are implemented in a compiled language, and therefore orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: This is one of the requirements of this assignment. To use only a few features of OpenCV.

Comment: Does the assignment specify that you must program in native Python only, and that the algorithm should be fast? Because those two things are mutually exclusive.

Comment: And by accepting the answer below, you’ve shown that “without any libraries” is not a real requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came up with can be summarized as follows:

- Convert the original image into grayscale and binarize through Otsu's method.
- Compute the connected components of the binary image.
- Select the largest region.
- Determine the extreme coordinates of that region.

```py
import numpy as np
from skimage import io
from skimage.measure import label, regionprops
from skimage.filters import threshold_otsu
from skimage.color import rgb2gray

img = io.imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIQjh.png')[:, :, :3]
gray = rgb2gray(img)

thresholded = gray > threshold_otsu(gray)
labels = label(thresholded, background=1)
props = measure.regionprops(labels)

largest = sorted(props, key=lambda x: x.area, reverse=True)[0]

top = np.where(largest.coords[:, 0] == largest.coords[:, 0].min())
bottom = np.where(largest.coords[:, 0] == largest.coords[:, 0].max())
left = np.where(largest.coords[:, 1] == largest.coords[:, 1].min())
right = np.where(largest.coords[:, 1] == largest.coords[:, 1].max())

extremes = np.concatenate([top[0], bottom[0], left[0], right[0]])
corners = largest.coords[extremes]
```

The code above relies not only in NumPy but also in scikit-image and is fairly efficient. Please note that this approach returns more than 4 points (you could readily cluster the coordinates to get just 4 points).

```py
In [419]: corners
Out[419]: 
array([[ 69, 417],
       [ 69, 418],
       [ 69, 419],
       [ 69, 420],
       [ 69, 421],
       [256, 211],
       [256, 212],
       [256, 213],
       [256, 214],
       [101, 187],
       [102, 187],
       [103, 187],
       [104, 187],
       [227, 460],
       [228, 460],
       [229, 460],
       [230, 460],
       [231, 460],
       [232, 460],
       [233, 460],
       [234, 460],
       [235, 460]], dtype=int64)
```

If you want to obtain a bounding box, you don't need to calculate them manually since the properties returned by `regionprops` have a key `bbox` that contains the coordinates of the bounding box:

```py
In [420]: largest.bbox
Out[420]: (69, 187, 257, 461)
```

**Demo**

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Circle

patches = [Circle((col, row), radius=25, color='green') 
           for row, col in corners]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.imshow(img)
for p in patches:
    ax.add_patch(p)
plt.show(fig)
```

[image: results]